# How to connect matplotlib LineCollection segments that have discontinuous x-axis boundaries?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

If you run the code or check out [example plot](https://ibb.co/NYnYh6h), you'll see discontinuities between x = (3,4) and (7,8).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

ranges = [(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 10)]
block_nums = np.arange(1, 11)
times = np.random.rand(10)

_seg_vals = [(block_nums[start:end + 1], times[start:end + 1]) for start, end in ranges]

line_colors = 'blue', 'orange'

line_segments = [np.column_stack([x, y]) for x, y in _seg_vals]


plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(line_segments, colors=('blue','orange')))
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

I could hack together something to define segments between the discontinuities, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution. Is there some way to tell matplotlib to connect the segments at the integer boundaries?

Comment: I don't think matplotlib supports it. But calculation lines of discontinuities is not that hard. Is it determined that length of discontinuities are unit?

Comment: If you want the lines connected then I’m not clear why you are making them segments instead of just doing plot(block_nums, times).  If, conversely, they are already organized as segments then you know the end and beginning of the lines and can just add segments between them.  But this code so pretty idiosyncratic, so matplotlib does not have a built in way to do this.

Comment: I used segments so I could change the color based on the x-value range. Is there another way to do this that isn't a line collection? @mathfux, the discontinuity will always be 1 if that's what you mean.

Comment: @base2 I'm doubtful it is another way. What's wrong with line collection? Also, if you are sure discontinuity is always 1 you might want apply `np.split` on `x` values and `y` values in one single step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doubtful `matplotlib` supports any way of drawing discontinuities but you can implement both of your `LineCollection`s in a shorter way. assuming capacity of each discontinuity is 1, no domain intervals are required and the only thing you need is a list of discontinuity points:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

marker_idx = np.array([3, 7])
xy_vals = np.transpose([np.arange(1, 11), np.random.rand(10)])
line_segments = np.split(xy_vals, marker_idx)

discontinuity_idx = np.transpose([marker_idx-1, marker_idx]).flatten()
discontinuity_line_segments = np.split(xy_vals[discontinuity_idx], 2)

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(line_segments, colors=('blue','orange')))
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(discontinuity_line_segments, colors=('lightgreen', 'lightgreen')))
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]